# How to apply nested while loops in python function

Tags: python, while-loop

I am learning python and trying to build a number guessing game.
The game will randomly generate integer between 1 to 250 (both inclusive) for user to guess. When user input is out of the range, it will prompt user that it is our of range and request another input. Likewise, it will prompt user if it is too high or too low until correct number is guessed. At any point in time if user input 'stop', it will end the game.
As part of the assignment requirement, i need to code 2 new functions on top of those already provided and incorporate it in the final run of the game.

I am trying to convert the while loops below to a function with not much progress. It either end with positional argument error or endless loop.

```
the_number = random.randint(1,250)

# capture initial user input
user_input = get_user_input()

# repeat code below as long as the user has not guessed the right number
while user_input != the_number:

    # repeat code below as long as user has not entered STOP
    while user_input != 'STOP':

        # verify user input is within range
        check_range(user_input)

        if user_input < the_number:
            slow_print("{} is too low". format(user_input))
            print('\n')
            user_input = get_user_input()

        elif user_input > the_number:
            slow_print("{} is too high". format(user_input))
            print('\n')
            user_input = get_user_input()

        else:
            slow_print("Congratulations you have guessed the correct number")
            break

    else:
        slow_print('\nGame stopped by user. Thank you for playing')
        break
```

Please can anyone suggest how I can convert the while loops into a function that works.

Comment: Well, what do your functions look like? That would be a good place to start. And exactly what error message do you get, including stacktrace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain what you are trying to achieve, but if all you need to do is add a further 2 functions then perhaps this is what you're looking for;

```
the_number = random.randint(1,250)

# capture initial user input
user_input = get_user_input()

# repeat code below as long as the user has not guessed the right number
while user_input != the_number:

    # repeat code below as long as user has not entered STOP
    while user_input != 'STOP':

        # verify user input is within range
        check_range(user_input)

        if user_input < the_number:
            tooLow(user_input)
            user_input = get_user_input()

        elif user_input > the_number:
            tooHigh(user_input)
            user_input = get_user_input()

        else:
            slow_print("Congratulations you have guessed the correct number")
            break

    else:
        slow_print('\nGame stopped by user. Thank you for playing')
        break

def tooLow(number):
  slow_print("{} is too low". format(number))
  print('\n')

def tooHigh(number):
  slow_print("{} is too high". format(number))
  print('\n')
```

Comment: Thank you Madison. Just for my own knowledge, is there a better way to do the while loop above?

Comment: You could use "while user_input != the_number or user_input != 'STOP':" otherwise I think it's fine.